# Correlated Expectation of Random Variables

Tags: integration, random-variables, normal-distribution, expectation, correlation

There are $2$ random variables $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y\sim N(0,1)$. These $2$ random variables are correlated, which can be given as $Corr(x,y) = \rho$

How do I compute an expectation of the below form?

$E[f(X) | Y > H]$ ?

$f(X)$ - It's a function of $X$.

$Y > H$ is a condition for computing the expectation. $H$ is a constant

How should I go about this?

If the condition did not exist I could have written this in the Integration Form. But with the condition how do I do that?

Comment: Well I am looking at how to compute the Integration to come to a closed form solution if there is one. Or at least how do I integrate to find the expectation?

Comment: If $(X,Y)$ is itself normal, then $Y=\rho X+\sigma Z$ where $(X,Z)$ is standard normal and $\rho^2+\sigma^2=1$ with $\sigma>0$ hence $$E(f(X);Y>h)=E(f(X);Z>(h-\rho X)/\sigma)=E(f(X)(1-\Phi((h-\rho X)/\sigma))$$ and $$E(f(X)\mid Y>h)=\frac{E(f(X)(1-\Phi((h-\rho X)/\sigma)))}{1-\Phi(h)}=\frac{E(f(X)\Phi((\rho X-h)/\sigma))}{\Phi(-h)}$$

Comment: @MANMAID As every `standard normal` couple, yes.

Comment: @Did - Is it possible to come up with a closed form solution of this if f(x) allows? Looks like the Numerator is going to be a double integral

Comment: No, the numerator is the simple integral $$\int_\mathbb Rf(x)\Phi((\rho x-h)/\sigma)\varphi(x)dx$$ where $\varphi$ and $\Phi$ are the standard normal PDF and CDF, respectively.

Comment: @Did - But how to go about this Integration? The CDF is not a constant in this case, it's a function of x in this case.

Comment: There is no reason to expect explicit formulas, except for very specific $f$ and $(h,\rho)$. Have you some values in mind?